# what noise is the water boiling pot making when boiling water?

Tags: food-science, boiling, water, stove

I tried to boil water in a Whistling boiling water kettle tea pot on a stove. The stove has electric stove top coil burners. So when boiling water with those,  there is some noise and sometime a sudden big noise like something hit the pot. I been living with the phenomenal forever but today, I just wanted to know why? what is the noise that the pot is making?

Comment: Thanks sir, what is attractive metal surface and unattractive water body?

Comment: Let's be mindful about "this isn't cooking" type statements - questions about physical explanations for things that happen as part of cooking are part of learning about cooking, and they're completely on topic here.

Answer (score 5):

[cavitation noise](https://www.mindat.org/glossary/cavitation_noise) - The noise produced in a liquid by the collapse of bubbles that have been created by cavitation.

Answer (score 2):

As the heat source is at the bottom, the water on the surface gets to the boiling temperature earlier than the rest of the pot/kettle. This causes lots of bubbles to form, and as they start moving up they come in contact with colder water and condense immediately.

Please note that, water vapor is much lighter than liquid water. Well... this is the very first reason it starts floating. But also this means all of a sudden there’s an instant increase in volume when the bubbles are forming, this is the first noise you’re hearing. 
And when these bubbles condense, they pop immediately and this is the second almost simultaneous sound/noise you hear.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned a "sudden big noise". The metal in the kettle expands as it heats, particularly the metal on the bottom (which is directly exposed to the heat). At a certain point, your kettle's bottom is compressed against the sides and [buckles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling), warping upwards or downwards in a way which relieves the compression. The mechanism of the noise is similar to the clicking noise when you press down on the tamper-evident "safety button" on the lids of some jars.

My guess is that if you press hard on some portion of the base of the kettle (you may need to press from inside the kettle) it'll make the same noise, though probably not as loud because it won't be resonating against the cooktop.